# How to Write a batch script for checking mulitple folders and folder inside a folder and set the csv files to variables?

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have to write a batch script to go inside multiple folders and folder inside a folder and set the CSV files inside it and set it to a variable.

my folder structure is

```
c:\data\client1\data1.csv
c:\data\client1\data2.csv
c:\data\client1\config\env.csv

c:\data\client2\data1.csv
c:\data\client2\data2.csv
c:\data\client2\config\env.csv
```

so like these I have many clients folder with config folder inside it and some data CSV's

now I have to use some loops to go inside "c:\data\" and check the client1 folder and inside I need to set var = data1.csv and var = data2.csv using for loop then I need to go inside config folder and set envs= env.csv (i.e the file name or path of the files)

I have tried a code but I am not getting the correct login on how to search and loop inside.

```
@ECHO OFF & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD "C:\data"
For /R %%A in (*.csv) DO (
  Set "file[!#!]=%%A"
  Set /A #+=1
  )
For /L %%B in (0,1,!#!) do Echo(!file[%%B]!
```

I modified the code as per the solution. But now I am unable to set the data1.csv in the client1 folder. and Can anyone explain this code? 
Can anyone help me with the logic of the coding part?

output is :

```
c:\data\client1\data2.csv
c:\data\client1\config\env.csv
c:\data\client2\data1.csv
c:\data\client2\data2.csv
c:\data\client2\config\env.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to assign them to an indexed variable.
With even moderately large file sets, a singular variable would exceed the line capacity, losing information assigned to it.

```
@ECHO OFF & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD "C:\data\client"
For /R %%A in (*.csv) DO (
    Set "file[!#!]=%%A"
    Set /A #+=1
)
For /L %%B in (0,1,!#!) do Echo(!file[%%B]!
```

Comment: Can you explain this code. This actually works but I am not getting data1.csv in output.
I am getting as:
C:\data\client1\data2.csv
C:\data\client1\config\env.csv
C:\data\client2\data1.csv
C:\data\client2\data2.csv
C:\data\client2\config\env.csv

Comment: /R is the switch to recursively process folders and their subfolders with a For loop. Try adjusting the line `CD "C:\data\Client"` to `CD "C:\data\"`. The Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion allows you to assign AND access new variables within code blocks such as for loops when combined with ! expansion of the variable.

Comment: The # counter is used as a combined variable within the file varaible to create a Pseudo Array, and provides a count for how many files were added to the array. The `For /L` Loop uses the value of the `#` variable to iterate over all the variables